# Different ways to say "even if"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

Are all of these grammatically correct and equivalent?

> Even if I fail
>
> Even should I fail
>
> Even if I should fail

What are the differences, if any? Could the last example be misinterpreted to mean that failing is a desirable outcome?

Answer (score 3):

All three are grammatically correct, and have the same meaning.  However, they are not grammatically equivalent: the first is set in the *future real (or "factual") conditional* tense, while the second and third are set in the *future unreal (or "counterfactual") conditional*.

[Conditional tutorial - Future conditionals](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/futureconditional.html)

[Wikipedia on conditional sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence)

Answer (score 1):

All of them are grammatically correct and mean the same thing. The last example means *"even if I did actually fail"*

Comment: All of them are grammatically correct, and essentially equivalent.  The ones with *should* are rather more old-fashioned, though, and would be less natural today unless you wand to sound deliberately old-fashioned.

Answer (score -1):

Every time you look at different phrases I find [ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=even%20should%20I%20fail,even%20if%20I%20should%20fail,%20even%20if%20I%20fail&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) really useful

[image]

(unfortunately you can't really choose which corpus is searched, but you can see in which books and publications the results were found).